# Set permissions to file stored using JCA in OSB

Tags: permissions, osb, jca, oracle-service-bus

I have a proxy which stores a file (Publish action) in a specific directory using a JCA File Adapter. I need to set permissions over the stored file, 777 for instance.

Does anyone know how/where to set it? Maybe a property in JCA file?

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue we had to use a java callout to set the permissions manually.

this is a bit of a dirty workaround and is to do with the permissions of the user who started the weblogic server.

in java there is two methods to try, but we used:

```js
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 file");
```

you might like to try,

```js
   file.setExecutable(false);
   file.setReadable(false);
   file.setWritable(false);
```